# PHP pushwoosh send

Tags: php, pushwoosh

I have this code :

```
public static function sendMessage($sMessage, $aTokens, $sDeeplink = NULL){
    # Create request
    $oRequest = CreateMessageRequest::create()->addNotification(Notification::create()->setContent($sMessage)->setDevices($aTokens)->setSendDate('now'));

    # Call the REST Web Service
    $oResponse = self::createPushInstance()->createMessage($oRequest);
    if($oResponse->isOk()){
        return true;
    }
    # Add logs
    self::addLogs($oResponse, 'sendMessage');

    return false;
}
```

How to prevent to not send to all users that are registered, but only for 2 for example ? It is possible ? I tried like this but push was sent to all registered devices (10.000).

Comment: Show us the code where you're calling `sendMessage`

Comment: Are you sure aTokens is valid and not null?
Which library do you use?